# How can I download files with wget?

Tags: python, python-3.x, wget

I am aware about `wget.download(url)`, but every time I get the error `AttributeError: module 'wget' has no attribute 'download'`. Do I have to use a different version of python? I am using python 3.7

Comment: What does `print(wget.__file__)` give you? My money is on you not importing the `wget` library you think you are importing...

Comment: Did you assign 'wget' as a variable somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I found the error was that the file was named `wget.py`.

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/57693822/2) to the question [How can I download files with wget? [Solved]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57693822/how-can-i-download-files-with-wget-solved) by the OP [TheRealTengri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10993097/therealtengri) under CC BY-SA 4.0.</sub>